# RAD and BlinkM, how to control a BlinkM, with an Arduino through RAD

Tags: serial-port, arduino

So I'm running [RAD](http://rad.rubyforge.org/) on my MacBook. I've been able to send serial commands with `screen` to the device and just light LEDs and simple stuff with the pins connected to the Arduino. However, I have been unable to use any of the [blinkM](http://thingm.com/products/blinkm) methods that RAD offers. They just fail to compile.

How do I control a blinkM with RAD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BlinkM module talks a protocol called [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C). This is supported in the standard Arduino library as part of [the Wire library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Wire), and the `BlinkM_funcs.h` header file that's provided with the sample sketches for the device use that.

According to the current RAD todo list, this library hasn't been ported to the RAD IDE yet.  It looks like you'll need to use the standard Arduino IDE and C/C++ code to interface with this.